# Does the magnetic field of earth restore?

Tags: the-sun, earth, magnetic-field, solar-wind

The magnetic field of earth protects us from solar wind as we know it, but after the solar wind interacts our magnetic field.

Does the magnetic field of earth restore after it deflects the solar wind from the sun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. After the charged particles that have distorted the magnetic field passed, it goes back to normal. Otherwise it could not have been doing this for the last few billion years.
This then looks something like this (data from the ACE satellite):

[image]

- And look [here](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/geospace-magnetosphere-movies) for awesome real-time data. (Thanks Magic Octopus Urn for the comment!)
- Or see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVS4Q4VgDxk) video for a more detailed simulation.

Comment: Interesting! Which direction does the Earth's spin point in this one? Also could you link a source for the data please?

Comment: This gif is actually pretty old and the exact source for the data not easily traceable.
See here: https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/dot7b/today_i_noticed_earth_was_hit_by_a_powerful/?sort=new

Comment: Here's some real-time data from that satellite: https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/ace-real-time-solar-wind

Comment: @Magic Octopus Urn Thanks, that is pretty awesome. I will add that to the answer, if thats ok.

Comment: @SpaceBread https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38428/what-is-being-shown-on-august-27th-from-the-noaa-ace-satellite I asked a follow-up about that data too.

Comment: @SpaceBread Approve

Answer (score 4):

Remember that a magnetic field is just that:  a **field** . There's no mass there.   Its shape depends on the electromagnetic properties of Earth -- primarily the behavior of the outer core.
When there's a significant Solar ejection,  the  electrically active particles in that mass cause local changes in the magnetic field pattern (equivalent to isobars , or lines of constant field strength, etc.)   So long as the solar ejecta do not damage the Earth in any significant way, once the particles are gone, the field lines will revert to their default layout.